# Auto-capitalize first letters in compound names (EditText, Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to automatic capitalise both first letters in compound names, for example: Gay-Lussac (French physicist), Иванов-Вано (Russian animation director).

Android EditText capitalises only first letter in whole name, and I get Gay-lussac and Иванов-вано.

Is there any method?

My EditText is

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences|textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Also I tried (also it does not work for second part):

```
        <EditText
            ...
            android:capitalize="words"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

and

```
        <EditText
            ...
            android:capitalize="words"
            android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: @LieRyan I'm not sure. I need to capitalise the second part of the name, after '-' character. Suggested solutions capitalise only first letter, after space or at the begin of field. Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could operate in 2 steps:

**1** - Have your strings **spaced** (ie.: `"Gay - Lussac"`) in strings.xml, and let Android capitalize them.
**2** - Then replace `" - "` with `"-"`, in Java.

**[EDIT]**

If the input is from the user, then replace step **1** step:

**1** - First, replace the user input string: `"-"` with `" - "`

Comment: I don't know all possible compound names, it was only samples. strings.xml can not help. Or I misunderstood your idea.

Comment: Where do you take the names from? Aren't they stored in strings.xml? Are they stored in a database?

Comment: I take names from users input. It is EditText, not TextView!

Comment: If so, you probably have to replace step (**1**): first replace the user input string: `"-"` with `" - "`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Class that contains a static method like this:

```
public static CharSequence capitalize(CharSequence name){

    if(name == null) return null;

    String sName = name.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    String result = "";

    sName = capFirst(sName);

    if(sName.contains("-")){

        result = "";
        String[] subParts = sName.split("-");

        for(int i = 0; i < subParts.length; i++){

            String subPart = subParts[i];
            result += capFirst(subPart);
            if(i < subParts.length - 1) result += "-";
        }           
    }
    else result = sName;

    return result.trim();
}

private static String capFirst(String text){

    if(text == null) return null;
    text = text.toLowerCase().trim();

    String result = "";

    if(text.length() > 0){

        text = text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);

        if(text.contains(" ")){

            for(String word : text.split(" ")){

                word = word.trim();
                if(word.length() > 0) result += " " + word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
            }
        }
        else result = text;
    }

    return result.trim();
}
```

Then add a listener to the apropriate event of your EditText and set it´s text using YourClass.capitalize().

Comment: It it the good idea, thank you. But it will be good behaviour do not capitalise again if user've changed capitalisation back.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own capitalisation. 
It capitalise last entered character if this character is last character in string and it is located after any non-letter character (or it is single character in string).

```
public class EditName extends EditText {
    public EditName(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            String lastChanged = "";
            boolean isLastSingleCharChanged = false;

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // check if only last character was changed
                isLastSingleCharChanged =
                        count - before == 1 // was added one character
                                && start + count == s.length() // last character was in changed group
                                && (start == 0 || count == 1); // or total change, or last character
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!isLastSingleCharChanged) return; // only if last character changed (see above)

                int len = s.length();
                if (len == 0) return;
                if (len > 1 && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(len - 2))) return; // correct letter only after none-letter

                char c = s.charAt(len - 1);
                if (!Character.isLetter(c)) return;
                if (!Character.isLowerCase(c)) return;

                String text = s.toString();
                if (text.equals(lastChanged)) return; // do not do the same correction twice

                lastChanged = text;
                EditName.this.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1)
                        + Character.toUpperCase(c));
                EditName.this.setSelection(text.length()); // position cursor
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```